# Jekyll - Can't Access Custom Front Matter Variables

Tags: yaml, jekyll, blogs, yaml-front-matter

I am new to Jekyll and would like to create additional variables in a Post Frontmatter:

```
style:
  name: post
img: image_name
```

When I try to use a variable like **title** it works

```
{% page.title %}
```

But when I try to use another variable

```
{% if page.img %}
  {{ page.img }}
{% else %}
  No image
{% endif %}
```

That returns nil. Even when simply trying to output

```
{{ page.img }}
```

Any idea why I can't use my custom variables defined in the frontmatter?

Comment: where are you putting the code? in a layout file? include? what is the whole front matter section? is there a repo to look at?

Comment: I just pasted your front matter into a test post, and then your code block below and it output `image_name` as expected. Do you have the closing 3 dashes on the front matter? your code works, there is something wrong other than the code itself I think.

Comment: Can you provide a repository url ? It's way more efficient for debugging.

Answer (score 12):

After some research I discovered that my YAML FrontMatter variables were not read inside a layout file, and found this link:

https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4123

So I changed

```
{{ page.img }}
```

to:

```
{{ layout.img }}
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should use {{ page.img }} instead of {% page.img %}. The percents in {% %} are usually for when you are doing something other than just calling a variable - like if statements, for statements, includes etc.

I wouldn't think {% page.title %} would work on its own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately {{ page.img }} does not output anything.